# Login not working sometime in cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp, controller, session-variables

I have customers_contoller.php in frontend

```
function login() {
 if(!empty($this->data)) {
  # Call function from Customer to insert Registration Data
  $loginData = ClassRegistry::init('Customer')->checkLogin($this->data['email'], $this->data['password']);
  if(isset($loginData) && !empty($loginData)) {
     $this->Session->write('Session.userid',$loginData['Customer']['id']);
     $this->Session->write('Session.email',$loginData['Customer']['email']);
     $this->redirect(HTTP_PATH."my-profile");
     exit;
  } else {
     $this->Session->setFlash('Please enter valid Username/Password','default',array('class'=>'flash_bad'));
 $this->redirect(HTTP_PATH."customer/login");
 exit;
  }
 }
}
```

and in model customer.php,

```
function checkLogin($email,$password) {
 $loginData = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Customer.email' => $email, 'Customer.password' => sha1($password), 'Customer.is_active' => 'Yes')));
 return $loginData;
}
```

**most of time Login working fine, but sometime login not working and also doesn't get Error Message. Only refresh page every time on login.**

I have just check all this things i found that when i can't login in my website at that time browser's cache show '/app/' for **Session path** but i have set actual Session path in **before_filter()** function in **app_controller.php** using `$this->Session->path = '/';`

I just remove all the browser's cache and try for login, now it is working fine.

Can anyone explain me what is the issue?
it occurs randomly so i can't find root of the issue.

Comment: Maybe you should try using the built-in Auth methods of CakePHP, that way you'll have a lot less code and no problems like this.

Comment: thanks but i can't use auth method because i use it in admin part using users table and in frontend i use customers table for that.

Comment: So, you have already use build-in Auth of CakePHP, aren't you? This is your second authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason of your problem is that Session is lost because of improper Cookie Path transmitted to browser. It may be happened randomly because of mixing of Session binding strategies of PHP (like by GET-parameter or by Cookies).

You have wrongly set up `$this->Session->path parameter`. It maps to **session.cookie_path** option of PHP. See quite similar example in [this](http://mbrisby.blogspot.com/2011/08/setting-sessioncookiepath-in-php.html) post.

`session.cookie_path` should exclude protocol, host and eventually port, so leave just root of you website `'/'`:

```
$this->Session->path = '/';
```

See also description of [Domain and Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path) options of cookies.

**EDIT**: In order to further investigate reason of Session misconfiguration, debug `SessionComponent` and `CakeSession` classes near `$base` argument passed to constructor:

- [/cake/libs/controller/components/session.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/controller/components/session.php)
- [/cake/libs/cake_session.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/cake_session.php)

I guess it was somehow passed wrongly, and you received `/app/` cookie path in the browser.

Comment: I already use $this->Session->path = '/'; in my website, by mistake i have just written that thing. i have edited my question. can you provide me other solution because its not working sometime.

Comment: Do you still see the problem? Do you asking why `/app/` path was transmitted to browser? Anyway I think you have problem with Session configuration rather than in your Authentication logic.

Comment: yes i still have a problem. i just check in cakephp, in that i set cookie timeout 1 minute, after automatic timeout i check cookie path it generate another cookie path for same website and website use that path. Like on logged in my Cookie path is '/' after automatic timeout its generate new Cookie path is '/app/'. I think there is an folder structure in cakephp is 'http://sitename/app/contollername/actionname' but using route i create 'http://sitename/contollername/actionname' so after automatic timeout it generate cookiepath '/app/'. can you help me?

Comment: No, the structure is not `sitename/app/controller/action`. Actually you place you controllers in `/app/controllers/` folder, say `/app/controllers/controllername.php` and your controller has a action method `actionname()`, then if you type `http://sitename/controllername/actionname`, cakephp will route the request to call `controllername.actionname()` method. This is default routing, so you should not configure anything in `/app/config/routes.php`

Comment: Do you type `http://sitename/app/controller...` in your browser to access the site? Please, attach configuration changes you performed.

Comment: Its done in my customers_controller i have add before_filter() function and add $this->Session->path = '/'; line again so its working properly now. Thanks for your all answers.