# CakePHP Client Login Issues

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I'm stumped. We have a client who cannot log in to our system and yet we can log in fine using her credentials. She can also log in fine from her friends home.

Upon entering her credentials the screen simply refreshes and nothing happens when in fact she should be brought to a dashboard page. When I monitor the request via the Chrome web developer tools I can see that the dashboard does get requested after log in but then suddenly we're brought back to the log in page.

Now I've cleared her cache, cookies and all other temporary internet files from both IE9 (her default browser) and Chrome. Nothing happens. I've read that changing session names might help but that did nothing either.

The system is using the newest version of CakePHP (2.2.1) and absolutely any help would be appreciated.

Comment: unexpected!!!!! Have you checked the entry in database?

Comment: Since you said it works fine from other networks I wonder if it is proxy related, like if somewhere in between she and the server there is a bad cache.

Comment: @petervaz thats sort of what I thought too. Currently she is tethering from her iPhone so I wasn't entirely sure.

Comment: I wonder it she go to youtapp/logout and then yourapp/login just for test. I myself not fully understand Auth::login() logic (especially part about login on system with any data).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382585/login-not-working-sometime-in-cakephp

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved. Turns out this client in particular had the wrong date and time set on her computer. Upon setting the correct date and time, she has been able to log in absolutely fine since.

Thanks everyone for help!